# Repeat output based on number of arguments input

Tags: python

Very very new to Python, the extent of my knowledge is what I've just built in the last few hours:

```
from sys import argv
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

script, gameid = argv

game = requests.get("http://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/game/" + (gameid))
r = game.text
root = ET.fromstring(r)
boardgame = root.findall('boardgame')
for b in boardgame:
    name = b.find('name').text
    year = b.find('yearpublished').text
    mech = b.find('boardgamemechanic').text
    cat = b.find('boardgamecategory').text
    print (name,",",year,",",mech,",",cat)
```

This is doing what I want it to which is to give me the four above pieces of information based on a user input.

What I'd like to know is if it's possible to run this script n number of times where n is the number of arguments entered at the cmd line?

The output looks like the following:

```
C:\Python>bgg.py 822
Carcassonne , 2000 , Area Control / Area Influence , City Building

C:\Python>bgg.py 25417
BattleLore , 2006 , Campaign / Battle Card Driven , Fantasy
```

What I'd like is if I could get something like the below:

```
C:\Python>bgg.py 822 25417
Carcassonne , 2000 , Area Control / Area Influence , City Building
BattleLore , 2006 , Campaign / Battle Card Driven , Fantasy
```

Cheers

Comment: Move your code into a loop. Can you query multiple ids at once from that site?

Comment: What part would I put into a loop and I'm not sure if I can query multiple at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key goal is to repeat the code that needs to do stuff more than once. To this end, extract your game IDs in a list from `argv` (you seem to know how this works already). Now, iterate across each ID and do for each, what you did for one in your original code.

```
from sys import argv
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

gameids = argv[1:]

for gameid in gameids: 
    game = requests.get("http://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/game/" + (gameid))
    r = game.text
    root = ET.fromstring(r)
    boardgame = root.findall('boardgame')
    for b in boardgame:
        name = b.find('name').text
        year = b.find('yearpublished').text
        mech = b.find('boardgamemechanic').text
        cat = b.find('boardgamecategory').text

        print (name, ",", year, ",", mech, ",", cat)
```

Now, invoke your program with `python bgg.py 822 25417` and you'll see the result you're looking for.

Comment: That's brilliant thank you! I had no idea where to do the loop / how to remove the original argv line. Thanks again!

Comment: @Accendi No problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for gameid in argv[1:]:
    ...
```

`[1:]` means a copy of the list without the first element (the script), it's called slicing.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response but I'm sorry completely new to Python, where would I put this in the above script?